# QGIS 3 Layers Panel - symbol color not the same as Categorized symbols on map

Tags: qgis-3, symbology

I have applied hex colors to the stroke and fill for a Simple Marker in the Symbol Selector from a join to an attribute table. Then I classified by a different column in the spatial table to give a text category in the Layers Panel. The colors on the map are correct, but the colors in the Layers Panel and the Layer Properties Symbology tab still show the color ramp. Is there any way around this?

*example - the two points are the same classification - text removed*
[image]

Comment: Some screen shots would help clarify your question!

Comment: Is it possible that > 1 point exists at the same location (visualize a stack of coins)?  If so, only the last (topmost) point is visible, and it has a different color than you expect.